# How can you create button dynamically with event handler in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++-2013

I have this:

```
btn->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this->dynamic);
```

but it says that a delegate constructor expects 2 arguments. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for `EventHandler`? The error already says that you need 2 arguments but you have only provided one. Find out what's the other one and plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

The constructor for EventHandler is:

```
EventHandler(
    object sender,
    EventArgs e
)
```

In your code you have provided `this->dynamic` which I would assume is your `object sender`. So you are missing `EventArgs e`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have solved it already, but i have another question. I have created a button that would create another button/s. But I want to see those buttons after I exit the program. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i have dynamic buttons. But if I will exit the program and run i again, the dynamic buttons are gone. So, my question is how can i make the dynamic buttons stay?